# Ruby Hashes - Creating a new key with the value of an empty array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, merge

So I have the following hash:

```
positions = {
      running: ["Kenny", "Joan", "Shabaz"],
      receivers: ["Luke", "Chris", "Megan", "Mark", "Mackenzie"],
      quarterback: ["Johnny"]
    }
```

In pry, I can add a `:linemen` key with an empty array to `positions` by using `team.merge({:linemen =>[]})` ...  However, this only works when manually input in a `pry` prompt.  I would like the end result to look like this:

```
positions = {
      running: ["Kenny", "Joan", "Shabaz"],
      receivers: ["Luke", "Chris", "Megan", "Mark", "Mackenzie"],
      quarterback: ["Johnny"]
      linemen: []
    }
```

What am I doing wrong for this `team.merge({:linemen =>[]})` to only work in pry?

Comment: Did you read the "merge" docs? Might also want to check out "merge!" The docs are your friend.

Comment: Note also that [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) is an alias for [Hash#merge!](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge-21).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
team.merge(:linemen =>[])
```

returns a new hash and doesn't change the receiver object. you can see what returns in pry because pry works that way, it shows you what an expression evalutes to.

If you want to change the receiver object you have to ways:

1) use merge! to change the receiver object instead

```
team.merge!(:linemen =>[])
```

2) assign the new hash to a variable (even the same works unless you need it unchanged)

```
team_with_linemen = team.merge(:linemen =>[])
```

Comment: ...and,  even more direct, `team[:linemen] = []`, though, unlike `merge!` that does not return the hash (it returns the value of `:linemen`: `[]`), though `team` is modified in the same way as with `merge!`.

Comment: @Ursus I was so stuck on the syntax in my argument that I didn't consider that sans `!` I was not actually changing the original hash, it's time for a break...  Thank you!